# How to make a horizontal bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

[image]

I am trying to create a horizontal bar that grows in colour strength given the numbers supplied to it in a flutter app. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: you should post a what you already tried as a starting point to give you advice. Without too much thinking I would go with a row containing two containers and use the flex parameters to separate the two bars....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use row with Expanded and Text

```dart
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 10,
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: 200 / 425, //current / max

            backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Text("value")
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use stack().
First make bar then on the top put Text() or what ever you want